# Scheduled tasks does not run during certain time in the night

Tags: java, windows, curl, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

One of the Scheduled tasks fails from 11:30 P.M in the night to 8:00 A.M in the morning, after which everything seems to work fine

**ERROR:**

**

> Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\Open_items" , instance
>   "{2f836ec9-04aa-4169-a364-33a2ac4fc9e4}" , action
>   "C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe" with return code 255.

**

The task is scheduled to "Run whether user is logged in or not", i can't find out whats causing the problem

The task runs a java program--> this in turn calls a batch file which uses CURL

Hope to hear on this, soon.

Comment: What is the task scheduled to do (exact command)? When is it scheduled to run? Do you leave the computer running, put it to sleep, or log off when the task is scheduled to run? Do you get any other error messages? Please tell us all of the information you can possibly give.

Comment: The task runs a batch file, that executes a java class file(this inturn calls another batch file).  The task runs on a server, so it is always running. No i do not have any error message apart from the one mentioned above to work on.

Comment: I'll admit to being a little sensitive on this one. About six years ago, I'd had a problem where a scheduled task would fail to run, but whenever I scheduled it, it would work happily. Finally, I found that the job would run - but only if its user-account was logged-in at the time. I notified my boss & the systems administrator. The SA went ballistic & spent two solid hours screaming at me that it was a well-known phenomenon that no-one in the universe had found a solution to (a fix had been issued 2 years before.) Naturally, I was dismissed as the SA was my boss's wife... Familiar scenario?

Answer (score 0):

[Error Code 255](http://www.hiteksoftware.com/mize/Knowledge/articles/049.htm) means **'The Extended Attributes are inconsistent'**. Check the URL and the other parameters before invoking the cmd.exe. Check if **'Open_items'** is a directory if that exists etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i invoke the cmd.exe with the same parameters through out, but for some reason it seems to fail only from 11 P.M to 8:AM

Comment: Is it possible for you to log the parameters and see what is going in there and execute the same thing manually?

Comment: i can do that, Although i don't think it would be helpful if i did it now, as the task fails only during the night.

Comment: Yes, do it at night and check.. there is no way to tell you unless you have the exact state of the sytem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies,  I was able to fix the error, it was with one of my batch files.

I was trying to compare the first digit of the hour(HH) in my batch file to a blank space

'%myHour%' == ' '

this was causing the issue.

"%myHour%" == " " ..This however works fine now